# SQL Server 2014: Either selected or all values in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is what I am trying to achieve. I have a procedure which receives employeeIds as optional arguments and stores them into a temp table (temp_table) like this

```
empId
-------
3432
3255
5235
2434
```

Now I need to run below query in 2 conditions:

**1st condition**: if argument is non blank then my query should be-

```
SELECT * 
FROM DEPARTMENTS 
INNER JOIN temp_table ON emp_no = empId
```

**2nd condition**: if argument is blank it will take all the rows from department table

```
SELECT * 
FROM DEPARTMENTS
```

One option I can use is:

```
IF (@args <> '')
BEGIN
    SELECT *  
    FROM DEPARTMENTS 
    INNER JOIN temp_table ON emp_no = empId
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM DEPARTMENTS 
END
```

But I am looking for a better option where I don't need to write almost same query twice. Please help.

Comment: The IF and ELSE queries are not entirely compatible because the IF query also returns `temp_table.empId` as a column (or even more if `temp_table` has more columns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to stick to what you are already doing.
It is the cleanest and safest way performance wise.

Comment: Also, it's the one that is easiest to understand for a different coder that has to figure out what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    DEPARTMENTS
WHERE   (
        @args <> ''
    OR  EXISTS  (SELECT 1 FROM temp_table WHERE emp_no = empId)
)
```